# CCLabelBMFont fnt file not working properly

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

so I have this:

```
CCLabelBMFont *timeLabel = [[CCLabelBMFont alloc] initWithString:@"abc" fntFile:@"clean_3.fnt"];
```

in a CCScene init method

using this font: http://fontstruct.com/fontstructions/show/clean_35 which is TTF

using this program to convert the format: http://www.angelcode.com/products/bmfont/ and tried http://www.n4te.com/hiero/hiero.jnlp .

I'm getting: "Invalid texture for sprite" error.

I have tried deleting the app off simulator and device and tried it again, same thing.
Any help would be appreciated. I do not want to use CCLabelTTF since I'll be updating this text every frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I forgot the PNG file. Thanks ubert!